# Setting out of stock using MAGMI?

Tags: stock, magmi

I want to set a products stock status to "out of stock". This is the csv file content:

```
sku;is_in_stock
2714575;0
```

After that, the stock status did not change in the backend. Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: in product detail page ?

Comment: Nope, admin area

Comment: please attach screen shoot which place exactly you want